# Sybase ASE tempdb table permission issue

Tags: sybase

I know sybase supports two types of temp tables, one starts with # and can't be shared by sessions. The other one is created with tempdb.. prefix which can be shared by sessions or users.

My question is:

Are tables created in tempdb accessible to other users as well?
How to control the access or how to prevent the table created by userA from being modified/dropped by userB?

I googled for a while but didn't find any information on this.

I'm using sybase at work but don't have admin access to create new user so I can't do the test.

Can someone who have experience please advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please refer to http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc32300.1570/html/sqlug/X10118.htm for details.

i also test the behavior on sybase ase 15.7.

the result as same as the previous link.

Are tables created in tempdb accessible to other users as well?

- Yes.

How to control the access or how to prevent the table created by userA from being modified/dropped by userB?

- There seems no method about the tempdb..xxx tables.

Comment: Permanent tempdb tables by default are created via the guest user. You can create these as tempdb.dbo.tablename if you have the correct dbo permissions in tempdb (usually gained from adding them in model so they are re-added each time the instance restarts),  otherwise it will be created as tempdb.guest.tablename by default.

You can permission permanent tempdb tables just like any other tables but by default users come in as 'guest' so you would really need to create them as tempdb.dbo.<tablename> then other users do not have access by default and would require specific permissions.